# Consistent histories and the CHSH game

Tags: quantum-mechanics

How does the "consistent histories" interpretation of QM explain the CHSH game in particular, in terms of physical descriptions (not mathematics, although I wouldn't mind some extra math on top of that if possible)?
Thank you very much in advance